# Reading an image with fread adds \0 in buffer

Tags: c, fread

I have a client and a server in HTTP, with the client I send a file to the server, and the server sends back the file to the client.

I have no problems sending files to the server, but when the server sends back big files that need to be sent in multiple pieces (e.g. images), every time I `fread` into my buffer, the buffer receives a `\0` somewhere, so the client receives a corrupted file.

Here's the code that sends back files to the client

```
            FILE* readFile = fopen(fileName, "rb");
            char buf[BUFFLEN];
            size_t readlen = 1;

            while (readlen != 0)
            {
                readlen = fread(buf, sizeof(char), BUFFLEN, readFile);
                write(socket, buf, readlen);
            }
```

What did I miss? This works with small text files.

Comment: Please note that `sizeof(char)` will never be anything but `1`.

Comment: How many bytes are you actually writing?  A partial `write()` seems likely.

Comment: My test image is around160kb.I send it 1024 at a time.

Comment: _"the buffer receives a \0 somewhere,"_. Where is "somewhere"?

Comment: I used the word "somewhere" because it's a different place for evey buffer...For example, in the first buffer it's in the 4th place, in the second buffer the 319th...etc

Comment: There is a `'\0'` in the data, so what? It's a valid value for binary data, and even for text data. It just signals the end of a string.

Comment: You should __send__ a binary image file to you server, then check its filesize on the server to see if everything (and no more) was received. The you __send__ it back to your client and check again and try to display it. Zeroes in binary data is normal.

Comment: OT: This `while`-loop, should be a `do`-loop.

Comment: The code completely lacks error checking. Not good.

Comment: Well the result isn't affected by the socket, i tried just making the ouput file locally and it's the same : I'm reading a 160kb image and the output is a 20kb corrupted image displaying the message "Error interpreting JPEG image file (Unsupported marker type 0x3b)"

alk : i remove all the ifs that check for errors to make it much more understandable

Comment: Does any code receiving via a socket loop around `read()`/`recv()` ***counting*** how much had been actually received?

Comment: You just only want to write as many bytes as `recv()`/`read()` told you!

Comment: Yes, my mistake was that the client checks for the strlen received instead of the real number of bytes received (strlen stops at the first \0...)

Comment: Just FYI: you did the right thing by adding the solution that worked for you as a proper **answer** (and you will also be able to [accept that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in a couple of days). There is no need to edit it inside your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved :

One of the answers made me realize my mistake. `\0` is NOT a wrong character. What was wrong was my client's way of receving the image. Everytime the client received a buffer, it would check for the strlen received, but `strlen(buffer)` STOPS when it encounters a `\0`. So i changed the number of bytes written from `strlen(buffer)` to the actual number of bytes read on the socket by the client.

Thanks to Iharob Al Asimi for the remark and to everyone for your help.